# Extracting data from GET request using axios

Tags: reactjs, get, axios, use-effect, use-state

I am having an issue of extracting data from axios GET request. Below is my code:

```
const Product = () => {
  const [cars, setCar] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://192.168.29.135:8000/data/cars");
      //console.log(res);
      setCar(res.data);
      console.log(typeof res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log(cars);
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  return <div>{cars.car_name}</div>;
}
```

The output for console.log(res.data) is this:

```
 {status: 1, message: "Cars List", data: Array(30)}
    data: (30) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    message: "Cars List"
    status: 1
    __proto__: Object
```

And the output for console.log(cars) is

> Undefined

So, I am unable to use the map function which gives me the error 'Map is not a function. I think I need to use this setCar(res.data.data). But even that is not working. Where am I going wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: When I am trying to do this return `<div>{cars.car_name}</div>` using `setCar(res.data.data)` I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'car_name' of undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

`setCar` is asynchronous so you can't get `cars` immediately after it is set, which is why you get `undefined` in the `console.log`.

However, cars are being set correctly to state, but because it's a list you can only `map` through it to be able to access the values.

Consider refactoring the `useEffect` to `setCars` only when data is available

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://192.168.29.135:8000/data/cars");
      if (res.data) {
        setCar(res.data);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

So your `return` should return JSX like this

```
return (
      <div>
            {cars.map(car => 
                <span key={car.id}>
                  {car.car_name}
                </span>
            )}
       </div>
);
```